# Retrofit разные модели в одном ответе

Tags: android, kotlin, retrofit

Имеется некоторый поисковый запрос, который возвращает JSON, содержащий разные модели в своем поле.

Пример

```
{
 "resultCount":13,
 "results": [
{"wrapperType":"collection", "collectionType":"Album", "artistId":40876509, "collectionId":259510974, "amgArtistId":310510, "artistName":"D+", "collectionName":"Dandelion Seeds", "collectionCensoredName":"Dandelion Seeds", "artistViewUrl":"https://music.apple.com/us/artist/d/40876509?uo=4", "collectionViewUrl":"https://music.apple.com/us/album/dandelion-seeds/259510974?uo=4", "artworkUrl60":"https://is4-ssl.mzstatic.com/image/thumb/Music/v4/67/d1/18/67d11843-724e-f40b-34ba-f94f087909c3/source/60x60bb.jpg", "artworkUrl100":"https://is4-ssl.mzstatic.com/image/thumb/Music/v4/67/d1/18/67d11843-724e-f40b-34ba-f94f087909c3/source/100x100bb.jpg", "collectionPrice":9.99, "collectionExplicitness":"notExplicit", "trackCount":12, "copyright":"℗ 1998 K Records", "country":"USA", "currency":"USD", "releaseDate":"2007-09-04T07:00:00Z", "primaryGenreName":"Alternative"}, 
{"wrapperType":"track", "kind":"song", "artistId":40876509, "collectionId":259510974, "trackId":259511004, "artistName":"D+", "collectionName":"Dandelion Seeds", "trackName":"Cut It Out", "collectionCensoredName":"Dandelion Seeds", "trackCensoredName":"Cut It Out", "artistViewUrl":"https://music.apple.com/us/artist/d/40876509?uo=4", "collectionViewUrl":"https://music.apple.com/us/album/cut-it-out/259510974?i=259511004&uo=4", "trackViewUrl":"https://music.apple.com/us/album/cut-it-out/259510974?i=259511004&uo=4", 
"previewUrl":"https://audio-ssl.itunes.apple.com/itunes-assets/AudioPreview71/v4/4e/fc/93/4efc93a5-f3f0-0c7e-ed14-68cb6b6d6fbd/mzaf_5721197462467928771.plus.aac.p.m4a", "artworkUrl30":"https://is4-ssl.mzstatic.com/image/thumb/Music/v4/67/d1/18/67d11843-724e-f40b-34ba-f94f087909c3/source/30x30bb.jpg", "artworkUrl60":"https://is4-ssl.mzstatic.com/image/thumb/Music/v4/67/d1/18/67d11843-724e-f40b-34ba-f94f087909c3/source/60x60bb.jpg", "artworkUrl100":"https://is4-ssl.mzstatic.com/image/thumb/Music/v4/67/d1/18/67d11843-724e-f40b-34ba-f94f087909c3/source/100x100bb.jpg", "collectionPrice":9.99, "trackPrice":0.99, "releaseDate":"1998-08-25T12:00:00Z", "collectionExplicitness":"notExplicit", "trackExplicitness":"notExplicit", "discCount":1, "discNumber":1, "trackCount":12, "trackNumber":1, "trackTimeMillis":236187, "country":"USA", "currency":"USD", "primaryGenreName":"Alternative", "isStreamable":true}, 
{"wrapperType":"track", "kind":"song", "artistId":40876509, "collectionId":259510974, "trackId":259511045, "artistName":"D+", "collectionName":"Dandelion Seeds", "trackName":"Green Party", "collectionCensoredName":"Dandelion Seeds", "trackCensoredName":"Green Party", "artistViewUrl":"https://music.apple.com/us/artist/d/40876509?uo=4", "collectionViewUrl":"https://music.apple.com/us/album/green-party/259510974?i=259511045&uo=4", "trackViewUrl":"https://music.apple.com/us/album/green-party/259510974?i=259511045&uo=4", "previewUrl":"https://audio-ssl.itunes.apple.com/itunes-assets/Music/v4/eb/c7/6a/ebc76a4f-3825-8060-f781-a0f36532f198/mzaf_876283245701275269.plus.aac.p.m4a", "artworkUrl30":"https://is4-ssl.mzstatic.com/image/thumb/Music/v4/67/d1/18/67d11843-724e-f40b-34ba-f94f087909c3/source/30x30bb.jpg", "artworkUrl60":"https://is4-ssl.mzstatic.com/image/thumb/Music/v4/67/d1/18/67d11843-724e-f40b-34ba-f94f087909c3/source/60x60bb.jpg", "artworkUrl100":"https://is4-ssl.mzstatic.com/image/thumb/Music/v4/67/d1/18/67d11843-724e-f40b-34ba-f94f087909c3/source/100x100bb.jpg", "collectionPrice":9.99, "trackPrice":0.99, "releaseDate":"1998-08-25T12:00:00Z", "collectionExplicitness":"notExplicit", "trackExplicitness":"notExplicit", "discCount":1, "discNumber":1, "trackCount":12, "trackNumber":2, "trackTimeMillis":170587, "country":"USA", "currency":"USD", "primaryGenreName":"Alternative", "isStreamable":true}, 
{"wrapperType":"track", "kind":"song", "artistId":40876509, "collectionId":259510974, "trackId":259511130, "artistName":"D+", "collectionName":"Dandelion Seeds", "trackName":"Don't Worry About Me", "collectionCensoredName":"Dandelion Seeds", "trackCensoredName":"Don't Worry About Me", "artistViewUrl":"https://music.apple.com/us/artist/d/40876509?uo=4", "collectionViewUrl":"https://music.apple.com/us/album/dont-worry-about-me/259510974?i=259511130&uo=4", "trackViewUrl":"https://music.apple.com/us/album/dont-worry-about-me/259510974?i=259511130&uo=4", "previewUrl":"https://audio-ssl.itunes.apple.com/itunes-assets/Music/v4/00/79/54/007954d4-c7f7-8900-cf96-1173ca7f608f/mzaf_5029393603193854925.plus.aac.p.m4a", "artworkUrl30":"https://is4-ssl.mzstatic.com/image/thumb/Music/v4/67/d1/18/67d11843-724e-f40b-34ba-f94f087909c3/source/30x30bb.jpg", "artworkUrl60":"https://is4-ssl.mzstatic.com/image/thumb/Music/v4/67/d1/18/67d11843-724e-f40b-34ba-f94f087909c3/source/60x60bb.jpg", "artworkUrl100":"https://is4-ssl.mzstatic.com/image/thumb/Music/v4/67/d1/18/67d11843-724e-f40b-34ba-f94f087909c3/source/100x100bb.jpg", "collectionPrice":9.99, "trackPrice":0.99, "releaseDate":"1998-08-25T12:00:00Z", "collectionExplicitness":"notExplicit", "trackExplicitness":"notExplicit", "discCount":1, "discNumber":1, "trackCount":12, "trackNumber":3, "trackTimeMillis":227293, "country":"USA", "currency":"USD", "primaryGenreName":"Alternative", "isStreamable":true}, 
{"wrapperType":"track", "kind":"song", "artistId":40876509, "collectionId":259510974, "trackId":259511261, "artistName":"D+", "collectionName":"Dandelion Seeds", "trackName":"Dandelion Wine", "collectionCensoredName":"Dandelion Seeds", "trackCensoredName":"Dandelion Wine", "artistViewUrl":"https://music.apple.com/us/artist/d/40876509?uo=4", "collectionViewUrl":"https://music.apple.com/us/album/dandelion-wine/259510974?i=259511261&uo=4", "trackViewUrl":"https://music.apple.com/us/album/dandelion-wine/259510974?i=259511261&uo=4", 
"previewUrl":"https://audio-ssl.itunes.apple.com/itunes-assets/AudioPreview62/v4/bd/42/36/bd423652-c476-10f5-a1f5-383adfa56eb4/mzaf_1251229812831649846.plus.aac.p.m4a", "artworkUrl30":"https://is4-ssl.mzstatic.com/image/thumb/Music/v4/67/d1/18/67d11843-724e-f40b-34ba-f94f087909c3/source/30x30bb.jpg", "artworkUrl60":"https://is4-ssl.mzstatic.com/image/thumb/Music/v4/67/d1/18/67d11843-724e-f40b-34ba-f94f087909c3/source/60x60bb.jpg", "artworkUrl100":"https://is4-ssl.mzstatic.com/image/thumb/Music/v4/67/d1/18/67d11843-724e-f40b-34ba-f94f087909c3/source/100x100bb.jpg", "collectionPrice":9.99, "trackPrice":0.99, "releaseDate":"1998-08-25T12:00:00Z", "collectionExplicitness":"notExplicit", "trackExplicitness":"notExplicit", "discCount":1, "discNumber":1, "trackCount":12, "trackNumber":4, "trackTimeMillis":231653, "country":"USA", "currency":"USD", "primaryGenreName":"Alternative", "isStreamable":true}, 
{"wrapperType":"track", "kind":"song", "artistId":40876509, "collectionId":259510974, "trackId":259511347, "artistName":"D+", "collectionName":"Dandelion Seeds", "trackName":"Profits Are Soaring", "collectionCensoredName":"Dandelion Seeds", "trackCensoredName":"Profits Are Soaring", "artistViewUrl":"https://music.apple.com/us/artist/d/40876509?uo=4", "collectionViewUrl":"https://music.apple.com/us/album/profits-are-soaring/259510974?i=259511347&uo=4", "trackViewUrl":"https://music.apple.com/us/album/profits-are-soaring/259510974?i=259511347&uo=4", "previewUrl":"https://audio-ssl.itunes.apple.com/itunes-assets/Music/v4/35/f3/46/35f34609-4e71-ae71-355b-c6ac72181730/mzaf_5686900859081999102.plus.aac.p.m4a", "artworkUrl30":"https://is4-ssl.mzstatic.com/image/thumb/Music/v4/67/d1/18/67d11843-724e-f40b-34ba-f94f087909c3/source/30x30bb.jpg", "artworkUrl60":"https://is4-ssl.mzstatic.com/image/thumb/Music/v4/67/d1/18/67d11843-724e-f40b-34ba-f94f087909c3/source/60x60bb.jpg", "artworkUrl100":"https://is4-ssl.mzstatic.com/image/thumb/Music/v4/67/d1/18/67d11843-724e-f40b-34ba-f94f087909c3/source/100x100bb.jpg", "collectionPrice":9.99, "trackPrice":0.99, "releaseDate":"1998-08-25T12:00:00Z", "collectionExplicitness":"notExplicit", "trackExplicitness":"notExplicit", "discCount":1, "discNumber":1, "trackCount":12, "trackNumber":5, "trackTimeMillis":249600, "country":"USA", "currency":"USD", "primaryGenreName":"Alternative", "isStreamable":true}, 
{"wrapperType":"track", "kind":"song", "artistId":40876509, "collectionId":259510974, "trackId":259511409, "artistName":"D+", "collectionName":"Dandelion Seeds", "trackName":"Rusted", "collectionCensoredName":"Dandelion Seeds", "trackCensoredName":"Rusted", "artistViewUrl":"https://music.apple.com/us/artist/d/40876509?uo=4", "collectionViewUrl":"https://music.apple.com/us/album/rusted/259510974?i=259511409&uo=4", "trackViewUrl":"https://music.apple.com/us/album/rusted/259510974?i=259511409&uo=4", "previewUrl":"https://audio-ssl.itunes.apple.com/itunes-assets/Music2/v4/8b/33/67/8b336773-9747-cafe-a624-2ea18a8069a6/mzaf_2729424859737659172.plus.aac.p.m4a", "artworkUrl30":"https://is4-ssl.mzstatic.com/image/thumb/Music/v4/67/d1/18/67d11843-724e-f40b-34ba-f94f087909c3/source/30x30bb.jpg", "artworkUrl60":"https://is4-ssl.mzstatic.com/image/thumb/Music/v4/67/d1/18/67d11843-724e-f40b-34ba-f94f087909c3/source/60x60bb.jpg", "artworkUrl100":"https://is4-ssl.mzstatic.com/image/thumb/Music/v4/67/d1/18/67d11843-724e-f40b-34ba-f94f087909c3/source/100x100bb.jpg", "collectionPrice":9.99, "trackPrice":0.99, "releaseDate":"1998-08-25T12:00:00Z", "collectionExplicitness":"notExplicit", "trackExplicitness":"notExplicit", "discCount":1, "discNumber":1, "trackCount":12, "trackNumber":6, "trackTimeMillis":316987, "country":"USA", "currency":"USD", "primaryGenreName":"Alternative", "isStreamable":true}, 
{"wrapperType":"track", "kind":"song", "artistId":40876509, "collectionId":259510974, "trackId":259511510, "artistName":"D+", "collectionName":"Dandelion Seeds", "trackName":"My Best Day", "collectionCensoredName":"Dandelion Seeds", "trackCensoredName":"My Best Day", "artistViewUrl":"https://music.apple.com/us/artist/d/40876509?uo=4", "collectionViewUrl":"https://music.apple.com/us/album/my-best-day/259510974?i=259511510&uo=4", "trackViewUrl":"https://music.apple.com/us/album/my-best-day/259510974?i=259511510&uo=4", "previewUrl":"https://audio-ssl.itunes.apple.com/itunes-assets/Music/v4/41/4c/a7/414ca717-b07d-b927-9ffa-8da8a231f2ac/mzaf_3343910103798289777.plus.aac.p.m4a", "artworkUrl30":"https://is4-ssl.mzstatic.com/image/thumb/Music/v4/67/d1/18/67d11843-724e-f40b-34ba-f94f087909c3/source/30x30bb.jpg", "artworkUrl60":"https://is4-ssl.mzstatic.com/image/thumb/Music/v4/67/d1/18/67d11843-724e-f40b-34ba-f94f087909c3/source/60x60bb.jpg", "artworkUrl100":"https://is4-ssl.mzstatic.com/image/thumb/Music/v4/67/d1/18/67d11843-724e-f40b-34ba-f94f087909c3/source/100x100bb.jpg", "collectionPrice":9.99, "trackPrice":0.99, "releaseDate":"1998-08-25T12:00:00Z", "collectionExplicitness":"notExplicit", "trackExplicitness":"notExplicit", "discCount":1, "discNumber":1, "trackCount":12, "trackNumber":7, "trackTimeMillis":188480, "country":"USA", "currency":"USD", "primaryGenreName":"Alternative", "isStreamable":true}, 
{"wrapperType":"track", "kind":"song", "artistId":40876509, "collectionId":259510974, "trackId":259511537, "artistName":"D+", "collectionName":"Dandelion Seeds", "trackName":"His Heels", "collectionCensoredName":"Dandelion Seeds", "trackCensoredName":"His Heels", "artistViewUrl":"https://music.apple.com/us/artist/d/40876509?uo=4", "collectionViewUrl":"https://music.apple.com/us/album/his-heels/259510974?i=259511537&uo=4", "trackViewUrl":"https://music.apple.com/us/album/his-heels/259510974?i=259511537&uo=4",
```

Как в этом случае отправлять запрос, и как потом разбирать?

```
fun getAlbumAndSongs(
        @Query("id") collectionId : Long,
        @Query("entity") entity: String = "songs"
    ) : Response<BaseResponse<T>>
```

Что вместо T указывать? Я же не могу указать 2 разные модели?

```
data class BaseResponse<T>(
    val resultCount : Int,
    val results : List<T>
)
```

**Update**

```
val baseEntity = body.results.map {
                        gson.fromJson(it.toString(), BaseEntity::class.java)
                    }
```

Падает с ошибкой

```
com.google.gson.JsonSyntaxException: com.google.gson.stream.MalformedJsonException: Unterminated object at line 1 column 142 path $.collectionName
```

Comment: *Падает с ошибкой* - по какой-то причине json не докачан. В примере в вопросе тоже обрубок - я думал вы просто не стали выкладывать целиком.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
fun getAlbumAndSongs(
        @Query("id") collectionId : Long,
        @Query("entity") entity: String = "songs"
    ) : Response<BaseResponse<JsonObject>>

// в функции 
val response = service.getAlbumAndSongs(id, entity)
if (response.isSuccessful) {
    val gson = Gson()
    val responseMap = response.body()?.results?.groupBy { it["wrapperType"].asString ?: "" } ?: emptyMap()
    // лист объектов где wrapperType == "collection"
    val collectionList = responseMap["collection"]?.map { gson.fromJson(it, Collection::class.java) } ?: emptyList()
    // лист объектов где wrapperType == "track"
    val trackList = responseMap["track"]?.map { gson.fromJson(it, Track::class.java) } ?: emptyList()
    // ...
} else {
    // обработать ошибку
}
```

`Collection` и `Track` тут это ваши дата классы для хранения соответствующих объектов

Comment: No get method providing array access

Comment: Type inference failed: Not enough information to infer parameter K in fun <K, V> emptyMap(): Map<K, V>
Please specify it explicitly.

Comment: @danilshik Обновите версию котлин плагина

Comment: оказалась не версия Kotlin, а нужно всего лишь изменить type в BaseResponce

Answer (score 1):

Примечание: решение предложено в случае, если для парсинга Json'а Вы используете Gson.

Структура классов:

```
data class BaseResponse<T>(
    val resultCount: Int,
    val results: List<T>
)

abstract class Answer {
    abstract val wrapperType: String
}

data class Collection(
    override val wrapperType: String,
    val collectionType: String
) : Answer()

data class Track(
    override val wrapperType: String,
    val kind: String
) : Answer()
```

Инициализация Gson:

```
val builder = GsonBuilder()
builder.registerTypeAdapter(Answer::class.java, InterfaceAdapter<Answer>())
val gson = builder.create()
```

Адаптер:

```
class InterfaceAdapter<T>: JsonDeserializer<T>{
    override fun deserialize(
        json: JsonElement?,
        typeOfT: Type?,
        context: JsonDeserializationContext
    ): T {
        val member = json as JsonObject

        val type = when(member["wrapperType"]?.asString){
            "collection" -> Collection::class.java
            "track" -> Track::class.java
            else -> return context.deserialize(json, typeOfT)
        }


        return context.deserialize(json, type)
    }

}
```

Код для ответа от сервера:

```
fun getAlbumAndSongs(
    @Query("id") collectionId : Long,
    @Query("entity") entity: String = "songs"
) : Response<BaseResponse<*>>
```

Получение данных:

```
val firstStep = api.getAlbumAndSongs(id)
val secondStep = BaseResponse(firstStep.resultCount, firstStep.results.map { 
    gson.fromJson(it.toString(), Answer::class.java) 
})
```

Решение является весьма некрасивым и написано на коленке, поэтому настоятельно рекомендую его улучшить. Если улучшить получится (или найти лучше) - дополните этот ответ, пожалуйста.

Comment: и что будет содержать secondStep? Answer?
Как мне из него получить например Song?

Comment: у меня it не видит

Comment: it - аргумент для map{}, будет странно, если его не видит...
secondStep будет содержать конченый ответ, Song можно получить 
val songs = secondStep.filter{ it is Song }

Comment: добавил код, падает с ошибкой

Answer (score 1):

Можно попробовать с помощью [хранения свойств в ассоциативном списке](https://kotlinlang.ru/docs/reference/delegated-properties.html).

Пример:

```
data class MusicItem(val wrapperType: String, val map: Map<String, Any?>)

data class Collection(val map: Map<String, Any?>) {
    val collection: String by map
    val collectionType: String by map
}

data class Track(val map: Map<String, Any?>){
    val kind: String by map
    val artistId: String by map
}


fun List<MusicItem>.getTracks(): List<Track> {
    return this.filter { it.wrapperType == "track" }.map { Track(it.map) }.toList()
}

fun List<MusicItem>.getCollections(): List<Collection> {
return this.filter { it.wrapperType == "collection" }.map { Collection(it.map) }.toList()
}

data class BaseResponse<T>(
val resultCount : Int,
val results : List<MusicItem>)
```

Использование:

```
val musicItems: List<MusicItem> = api.getAlbumAndSongs(id).results
val tracks = musicItems.getTracks()
val collections = musicItems.getCollections()
```

P.S. костыль ещё тот конечно, но вроде бы чуть проще, чем в предыдущем ответе.

P.P.S. моё мнение - лучше бы переделать API, чтобы возвращал разные модели в разных массивах

P.P.P.S. Добавил [функции-расширения](https://kotlinlang.ru/docs/reference/extensions.html) для List, так вроде более удобно использовать.

Comment: это не мой API, это Itunes Api такой

Comment: а как планируется использовать результаты? они нужны одним списком?

Comment: сначала занести в бд в виде класса, а потом работать с ними